# When taking a copy of the node template do you need to maintain the article tag that is in there

Tags: 7, theming

When taking a copy of the node template, should you keep/maintain the original code that is in the file?

Example the article tag.

nid; ?>" class=" clearfix"> etc..

What are the implications of removing this, if any?

Comment: remove it and find out.

Comment: If you keep the original code then what is the point of making a copy. You are making the copy so that you can make changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you're free to edit templates !

- The theme's css might depend on some tags, especially the article tag, so you could **lose layout/design**
- If you're a forward thinking brave drupalista you definitely want to keep title logic and the possibility of rendering all fields (and comments) and respect the view modes ;)